# CentOS 7 /proc/net/ip_conntrack: No such file or directory

Tags: munin, centos7

yesterday I must hard-reset my server and from the reset I can see the following problem in the `munin-node.log`:

```
2015/04/28-04:10:02 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58663" Local: "[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4949"
2015/04/28-04:10:03 [10824] Error output from fw_conntrack:
2015/04/28-04:10:03 [10824]     cat: /proc/net/ip_conntrack: No such file or directory
2015/04/28-04:10:04 [10824] Error output from fw_forwarded_local:
2015/04/28-04:10:04 [10824]     Can't find conntrack information
```

And munin is not generating `Connections through firewall` graph and `ipconntrack` graph anymore.

Before the server reset munin works correctly (I can include graph images).

Do you have some tips, links or something like that to solve this problem, please? I am sorry, but my knowledges of server configurations are not as good.

Comment: check if iptables is running, additionally you might want to try if the module is there:
modprobe ip_conntrack

possible after the restart your system did boot another kernel.

Comment: no, it's not running `iptables.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)` and I can't start it: `systemctl start iptables 
Failed to issue method call: Unit iptables.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make updates without rebooting? You might want to check if you use firewalld instead of iptables and can just start that service again.

```
service firewalld restart
```

If that not helps or really use iptables try the next option:

```
yum install iptables-services
```

That should let iptables start again and remove the error in munin.

However if you used firewalld before the restart this possible could relate in further issues so really make sure you find out/know which one you do use!

Comment: `systemctl start firewalld` solved my problem ... I'm really bad server admin .... I hope, that `systemctl enable firewalld` resolve my future reboot problem. Thank you for stimulus to resolve this problem.

Comment: @pes502 feel free to upvote or even accept  the answer. I changed it to include your solution,